# No mapping exists from object type ,System windows form

Tags: c#, ado.net

I try to use ADO.NET to connect to SQL Server databases. I try to build a windows form and put some textbox and button so I can input value and check the record in database. But the result says No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms, Textbox to a known managed provided native type.

So, could you give me some suggestion?

I implement the code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace casestudy
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection vcon1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SOPHIA-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=casestudy;Integrated Security=True");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
            vcon1.Open();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error.occured" + ex.Message);
            this.Dispose();
        }

    }
    private void Find_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string querystring = "SELECT * FROM AssignedSolution WHERE CASEID = @caseid";
        SqlCommand Vcom = new SqlCommand(querystring, vcon1);
        Vcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caseid", txtCASEID);
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try
        {
            Vcom.Connection = vcon1;

            Vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();


            rdr = Vcom.ExecuteReader();
                            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);

            }
            Vcom.Dispose();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error.occured" + ex.Message);

        }
           finally
           {
              vcon1.Close();
              vcon1.Dispose();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also in this method `Form1_Load` you do not need to open the connection there, makes zero since.. put it in the click event and look up how to use the `using( ){ }` construct with `Sql Data Objects` so you do not have to explicitly call the `Dispose()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is on this line:

```
Vcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caseid", txtCASEID);
```

Try this instead:

```
Vcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caseid", txtCASEID.Text);
```

You're attempting to provide the value from a `TextBox` to a `SqlParameter`.  The `AddWithValue` method takes as arguments the parameter name and its value, but the value argument is of the type `object`, so you don't get any complaint from the compiler by trying to assign it `txtCASEID`.  However, `txtCASEID` is a *`TextBox`* not a `string`; you need to use its `Text` property to get the `string` value, hence `txtCASEID.Text`.

Comment: Hi Roryap,Thank you so much! I have add a Text so it do not return me any error this time. But, I cannot see the record when I click find. I don't know whether I need to add a DataGridview or Datareader? I don't know how I can see the result on the form .